# Четность/нечетность отрицательных чисел

Tags: c++, if, условия

Возможно глупая ошибка, но сам разобраться не могу. Есть цикл на проверку четности в программе. Все нечетные числа нужно поделить на среднее арифметическое всех чисел. Вот фрагмент.

```
void input (ofstream &in) {
vector <int> arr;
generate_n (back_inserter (arr), 100,
            [] {return rand() % 101 - 50;});
transform(arr.begin(),arr.end(),
          ostream_iterator<int>(in, "   "),
          [] (int x) {return x;});
}
vector <int> inputfile(ifstream & out) {
    vector <int> arr;
    transform(istream_iterator<int>(out),istream_iterator<int>(), back_inserter(arr), [] (int x) {return x;});
    return arr;
}
vector <int> modify (vector <int> & other) {
    int var = 0;
    vector <int> arr;
    var = accumulate(other.begin(), other.end(), 0) / 100;
    cout << "Sum of Array = " << var << endl << endl;
    transform(other.begin(), other.end(), back_inserter(arr), [&var] (int x) {
        if (x % 2 == 1) //здеcь задается условие проверки
            x /= var;
        return x;
        });
    return arr;
}
```

Дело в том что программа делит только положительные нечетные числа, а отрицательные игнорирует

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Замените условие

```
if (x % 2 == 1)
```

на условие

```
if (x % 2 != 0)
```

Проблема в том, что первое условие для отрицательных чисел дает отрицательный остаток.:) Посмотрите результат этой демонстрационной программы

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int x = -11;

    std::cout << x % 2 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
-1
```

Обратите внимание на то, что вместо алгоритма `std::transform` в том контексте, в котором вы его используете, проще использовать алгоритм `std::copy`.

Comment: или == заменить на &

Answer (score 1):

Возможна проверка используя операцию логическое И.

```
    int a = -10;
    int b = -11;

    std::cout<< (a & 1)<<'\n';
    std::cout<< (b & 1)<< '\n';
```

> output:
>
> 0
>
> 1